Keep getting RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms error
I am connecting to a SQL Server using the mssql node library https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connections-1. When I try to run a long stored procedure, I keep getting a timeout error even though I adjusted my timeout time in the config.

RequestError: Timeout: Request failed to complete in 15000ms
at Request.userCallback (/Users/u1149864/Projects/my_app/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious/request.js:811:19)
at Request.callback (/Users/u1149864/Projects/my_app/node_modules/tedious/src/request.ts:379:14)
at /Users/u1149864/Projects/my_app/node_modules/tedious/src/connection.ts:3801:24
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
code: 'ETIMEOUT',

My Node JS code:
await sql.connect({
      user: dbUser,
      password: dbPassword,
      server: dbServer,
      database: dbName,
      connectionTimeout: 300000,
      requestTimeout: 300000,
      pool: {
        idleTimeoutMillis: 300000,
        max: 100,
      },
    });

    const request = new sql.Request();

    const result = await request.execute(STORED_PROC_DATA_VALIDATION);


Have you tried reading the Tedious documentation? requestTimeout isn't specified in the correct place, so will have no effect.

@AlwaysLearning I added to the options object and it still did not work. options: {         requestTimeout: 0,  },

Figured it out, it was related to another error.

@user7659932 don't leave is hanging!
